# fixing offline yum RHEL7 missing dependancy, libnsl, local repository and --skip-broken

Tags: rhel, yum, dependencies

On a RHEL 7.9 system that is off network, a `reposync` is used to transfer ~200gb worth of repo data to it, including EPEL.  That local repository on the system is working fine as far as i can tell.

Problem is when doing `yum update` which this process worked completely fine last month, I receive some hundred errors, much of which were *kdf5* and *perl* stuff.  I managed to `yum remove` all of the errors except for `tcp_wrappers-libs` which complained about *nothing provides `libnsl.so`*.  However I completed the update by doing `yum update --skip-broken` to get past this one and only item.

- Is it ever ok to use `--skip-broken` when doing `yum update`?  What about the scenario I just described?
- Is this a problem on my end, or with EPEL?  As far as I can tell I have not missed anything in downloading and transferring to my offline system.
- A mostly identical RHEL-7.9 server that is online and connected to the RHEL and EPEL repo's does not have this problem; it has `/lib64/libnsl-2.17.s0` but a `yum provides libnsl-2.17.so` responds with *no matches found*.
- What is the proper way to fix this issue on my offline server?

Just recognized it is`libnsl.so.1` that yum errors on, and a `yum provides libnsl.so.1` responds with `glibc-2.17`.

Comment: Did you remove `glibc`?  that would likely cause a few problems.

Comment: no i did not remove glibc